# why is the output contains 4 time 0's?

Tags: c

why is the output contains 4 time 0's.The main call again and again until if condition become false and then it should be exit from if block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        static int i=5;
        if(--i)
        {           
            main();
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What output were you expecting? Did you try working it out by hand?

Comment: why did printf statement execute?

Comment: `printf()` is what comes after the recursive call to `main()`, and thus it gets called when the stack starts unwinding.

Comment: Ok thank you, I got it

Answer (score 0):

Note the following.

1. the int `i` is static.
2. you are calling `main` reursively.
3. In the `if` condition you have a pre decrement of `i`

Every time you call main, the value of `i` will be the same as the previous call. So `i` will decrement each time. Since this is `--i` it will be 4 the first time and go to 0.

After the innermost main function returns(`i==0`), the `printf` of the main before that will be executed.

But `i` is static and has a value of `0`. So you get 4 zeros printed for each of the main functions.